# Calling the pods using pod's name instead of host and port

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, coredns

I'm running set of micro-services inside of a local minikube cluster (using helm charts) which communicate each other. Each and every service's host and port passed via `value-dev.yaml` to the other services and communication works fine. Now I need go bit of further, and alter connection calling from `http://helm-chart-name:PORT/` to `http://helm-chart-name/` or `http://service-pod-name/`. I tried to do this but it didn't work. Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Services (specifically) set the `port:` number to 80.  This is the default TCP port number for HTTP, so it's the port number that will get used if there's not a `...:12345` port number in a URL.  The `targetPort:` needs to match whatever port the pod is listening on; it doesn't need to match the `port:`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "chart.fullname" . }}
spec:
  selector:
    {{- include "chart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80          # default HTTP port
      targetPort: 3000  # port number the matching Pod uses
```

Now other services can call `http://helm-chart-name/` without explicitly giving a port number.

(You pretty much always need to use a Service to accept connections into a pod; you don't generally communicate directly to a pod, and aside from some specialized circumstances it's tricky to do so.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access with pod, The DNS resolution is as follows:
`pod-ip-address.deployment-name.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`. Given the ephemeral nature of pods and likelihood of running more than one pod of same kind, I would recommend using Service abstraction for intra-cluster communication like what you require. Services resolve to DNS of this format `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`. You can also have headless Service and resolve to Pod with specific (host)name. Refer to [DNS Reolution details here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)